# Freemarker Set checkTemplateLocation via Java

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have a Spring Boot web application. I am using Freemarker as my ViewResolver and I configure everything via java.  I am getting a warning in my log file:

```
2018-02-07 19:00:28,592 WARN  o.s.b.a.f.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration - 
Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] 
(please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
```

I have my templates in an external location so the warning is correct.

I have my config set up like this:

```
@Bean 
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() { 
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer(); 
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath(freeMarkerConfiguration.getBasePath());
    return freeMarkerConfigurer; 
}
```

The templateLoaderPath is an external file:  location and does have templates.  In fact,  everything is working fine,  I just want to get the warning out of my log file, but has taken me down a rabbit hole that I now need to figure out.
So I added that property to my configuration like this:

```
@Bean 
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() { 
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer(); 
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("checkTemplateLocation", "false");
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath(freeMarkerConfiguration.getBasePath());
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(props);
    return freeMarkerConfigurer; 
}
```

this is throwing an error:

```
 Unknown FreeMarker configuration setting: "checkTemplateLocation"
```

I have tried "freemarker.checkTemplateLocation" and "spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation"  and neither have worked.

How do I set this setting via a Java configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing FreeMarker Configuration settings, which are unrelated to Spring, with Spring's configuration properties. `spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation` is a Spring-specific thing, that you can, for example, put into your `application.properties`. FreeMarker Configuration settings are defined by FreeMarker, and note that they aren't called "properties", but "settings"; maybe the confusion comes from that you are using a `java.util.Properties` object to specify them.

Though of course the best would be to get rid of the cause of the warning... does your `setTemplateLoaderPath` call happen later than the WARN logged?